# SwiftUI Struct Array - can display values in ContentView

Tags: ios, json, iphone, swiftui

I am trying to display values from my API call.

```
   VStack(alignment: .leading) {
        HStack(alignment:.top) {
            Text("\(network.loan?.account ?? "no account")").bold()
            
            VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                
                Text(network.loan?.primaryBorrower.fullName ?? "").bold()
                Text(network.loan?.primaryBorrower.street ?? "")
                Text(network.loan?.primaryBorrower.city ?? "")
                Text(network.loan?.primaryBorrower.state ?? "")
                Text(network.loan?.primaryBorrower.zipCode ?? "")
                //This is where I want to add Terms based on desired Key(s)
                //Terms - Key: "PurchaseDate", Value: "01/01/2019"
                //Terms - Key: "NoteRate", Value: "6.20%"



            }
        }
        .frame(width: 300, alignment: .leading)
        .padding()
        .cornerRadius(20)
    }
```

Here is an example of what my struct looks like.  Terms is an array of many Key/Values.  I want to be able to display specific ones based on the Key Name.

```
struct Loan: Codable {
    let type, account: String
    let byLastName: String?
    let terms: [String: String?]


    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case type = "__type"
        case account = "Account"
        case byLastName = "ByLastName"
        case terms = "Terms"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try something like this:

For individual:

```
if let loan = network.loan {
    Text("PurchaseDate")
    if let value = loan.terms["PurchaseDate"], let val = value {
        Text(val)
    } else {
        Text("no value")
    }
}
```

For all:

```
if let loan = network.loan {
    ForEach(Array(loan.terms.keys), id: \.self) { key in
        HStack {
            Text(key)
            Spacer()
            if let val = terms[key], let value = val {
                Text(value)
            }
        }
        Divider()
    }
}
```

Or something like this:

```
if let loan = network.loan {
    List {
     // ForEach(loan.terms.sorted(by: {$0.key < $1.key}), id: \.key) { key, value in
        ForEach(loan.terms.reversed(), id: \.key) { key, value in
            Section(header: Text(key)) {
                if let val = value {
                    Text(val)
                }  else {
                    Text("no value")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```